# mysql_num_rows is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginner in PHP. when I try to do mysql_num_rows it is giving an error:

> Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object
>   given in D:\xampp\htdocs\kcp\police\viewcase.php on line 22

This is the code:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['pusername'])||empty($_SESSION['pid']))
{
    header('location://localhost/kcp/police_login.html');
    exit();

}
else
{
    $station=$_SESSION['station'];
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','kcp');

    if(!$con)
    {
        echo 'NOT CONNECTED TO DB';
    }
    $sql="SELECT * FROM complaint WHERE station='$station'";
    mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
    $res=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die("llllllll");

    $numrow=mysql_num_rows($res);
    echo $numrow;
}

?>
```

Comment: If you use the `mysqli` object-oriented interface these mistakes are pretty much impossible, a single missing `i` won't tank your code. The procedural style was intended for compatibility with PHP 4, which is now long dead. Even better, use PDO which is not MySQL specific and generally all-around easier to use.

Answer (score 5):

You can't mix up mysql and mysqli.

```
$numrow = mysqli_num_rows($res);
echo $numrow;
```

[mysqli_num_rows() Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Answer (score 0):

Use mysqli_num_rows instead of mysql_num_rows